# Cant create regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i need regular expression (Regex.Match) for any combination of following symbols

```
a-z
A-Z
0-9
()[]_-.
```

Length is from 2 to 16 symbols. 
Examples:

```
asdqwe23))
asd[-_]QWE
0(.)qwe[zz_-].
```

Ive tried this

```
^[\w\d\r\n\d\[\]\(\)-_]{2,16}
```

but it doesnt work, it allows !@#$%^&* symbols at any place except 1st. Also 17+ length strings also returns isSucsess true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this regex `^[_a-zA-Z\d\[\]\(\)\-\.]{2,16}$`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var input = "asd[-_]QWE";
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"^[A-Za-z0-9\(\)\[\]_\-\.]{2,16}$");
Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
```

Comment: your regex match 17+ length strings